# How to use Prometheus labels as drop down items in Grafana dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a single Prometheus instance running one job that is targetting three seperate Postgres servers. My Prometheus config is as follows:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name:  'quoters'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['172.17.0.1:9187']
      - labels:
          instance: quoter-dev
      - targets: ['172.17.0.1:9188']
      - labels:
          instance: quoter-staging
      - targets: ['172.17.0.1:9189']
      - labels:
          instance: quoter-prod
```

I have added Prometheus to Grafana as a data source and I have imported an example dashboard (https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14114)

I would like it to be configured such that the "instance" labels from the Prometheus config populate the "instance" drop down in Grafana.

However as it stands the closest I can get to that is a drop down of the target IPs and ports.

In Grafana my instance query is `label_values(instance)`

I know I am close, but cannot get it to show the labels rather than the targets

Any ideas will be appreciated!